# What's the difference between .show() and .css({'display':'block'})?

Tags: jquery, css

I just got a script to work by changing

```
$('#thisElement').show();
```

to

```
$('#thisElement').css({'display':'block'});
```

where `#thisElement` had been loaded as having `display:none;`

Is there a fundamental difference in these two expressions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you have this at the beginning:

```
<span id="thisElement" style="display: none;">Foo</span>
```

when you call:

```
$('#thisElement').show();
```

you will get:

```
<span id="thisElement" style="">Foo</span>
```

while:

```
$('#thisElement').css({'display':'block'});
```

does:

```
<span id="thisElement" style="display: block;">Foo</span>
```

so, yes there's a difference.

Comment: I just tried this and it is in fact correct. I think the jQuery documentation is a bit unclear. When you call show() after calling hide(), the value is restored to what it was initially. If you call show() and hide() was never called, it sets the display value to an empty string. (see: http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=1.4&fn=show)

Answer (score 3):

From the [jQuery show() documentation](http://api.jquery.com/show/):

> This is roughly equivalent to calling .css('display', 'block'), except that the display property is restored to whatever it was initially. If an element has a display value of inline, then is hidden and shown, it will once again be displayed inline.