# How to do "display = block" using jquery for particular element

Tags: jquery, css

I am using the following CSS code to hide an element.

```
#DeltaPlaceHolderLeftNavBar div>div>ul>li>ul
{
     display:none;
}
```

Now I am trying to make it visible using following jquery code but it is not working.

```
$('#DeltaPlaceHolderLeftNavBar div>div>ul>li>ul').style.display = 'block';
```

How to make it work?

Comment: Spend an hour reading through [the jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com). It'll save you a lot of time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [.css()](http://api.jquery.com/css/)

```
$('#DeltaPlaceHolderLeftNavBar div>div>ul>li>ul').css('display', 'block')
```

Comment: Your "Simply use" won't work http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3641532/whats-the-difference-between-show-and-cssdisplayblock in this case

Comment: Thanks @KamranAhmed for point out. I learned something today :). Edited answer

Answer (score 1):

The 'official' jQuery way to do this is to use the function provided by jQuery for this being

```
 $('#DeltaPlaceHolderLeftNavBar div>div>ul>li>ul').show();
```

Do note however that this only works if the `display:none` is inline rather than in your CSS as no explicit `display:block` declaration is added.

So if you want to explicitly set the CSS manipulation you may also wish to use

```
 $('#DeltaPlaceHolderLeftNavBar div>div>ul>li>ul').css('display', 'block')
```

Or even get the pure element and change the styling of the pure element

```
 $('#DeltaPlaceHolderLeftNavBar div>div>ul>li>ul').get(0).style.display = "block";
```

Lastly it's a very good idea to not change css properties at all, but remove and add classes, like for example having a class `.activated` and removing it when the element is hidden (where `display:block` is only set for the activated state)

```
 $('#DeltaPlaceHolderLeftNavBar div>div>ul>li>ul').removeClass('activated')
```

The very important advantage of this is that you only change the state of the DOM and the CSS handles the way it should respond to that, rather than mixing CSS and javascript with eachother.

Answer (score 0):

best solution is to use this way:

```
$('#DeltaPlaceHolderLeftNavBar div li > ul').show();
```

`.show()` will add the style to `display:block;`.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b5WW4/)

Comment: Not exactly. Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3641532/whats-the-difference-between-show-and-cssdisplayblock

Comment: @KamranAhmed why not?

Comment: Have a look at this question

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3641532/whats-the-difference-between-show-and-cssdisplayblock

Answer (score 0):

Try `$('#DeltaPlaceHolderLeftNavBar div>div>ul>li>ul').css('display', 'block')`

**UPDATE**

`$('#DeltaPlaceHolderLeftNavBar div>div>ul>li>ul').show()` might not work as there is a [difference between them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3641532/whats-the-difference-between-show-and-cssdisplayblock). So `$('#DeltaPlaceHolderLeftNavBar div>div>ul>li>ul').css('display', 'block')` is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
$('#DeltaPlaceHolderLeftNavBar div>div>ul>li>ul').prop('display', 'block');
```

or

```
$('#DeltaPlaceHolderLeftNavBar div>div>ul>li>ul').show();
```